# GoogleDrive C# SDK: Too much items in FileList

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

When I retrieve all Files (and Folders) of my GoogleDrive Account I should get something like 1500 List elements back, but I get a bit more than 3000 back. I looked into the List and found that some files are 2-3 times in it. Why is that?

Here is the code I use to retrieve the files:

```
public async Task<List<File>> RetrieveAllFilesAsList(DriveService service, string query = null)
    {


        List<File> result = new List<File>();
        FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();

        if (query != null)
        {
            request.Q = query;
        }

        do
        {
            try
            {
                FileList files = await request.ExecuteAsync();

                result.AddRange(files.Items);
                request.PageToken = files.NextPageToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred (from RetrieveAllFilesAsList): " + e.Message);
                request.PageToken = null;
            }
        }
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

        return result;

    }
```

Update1:

```
        public async Task<List<File>> RetrieveAllFilesAsList(DriveService service, string query = null)
    {
        List<File> result = new List<File>();
        FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
        request.MaxResults = 1000;

        if (query != null)
        {
            request.Q = query + " AND trashed=false";
        }
        else
        {
            request.Q = "trashed=false";
        }

        do
        {
            try
            {
                FileList files = await request.ExecuteAsync();

                result.AddRange(files.Items);
                request.PageToken = files.NextPageToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred (from RetrieveAllFilesAsList): " + e.Message);
                request.PageToken = null;
            }
        }
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < result.Count; i++ )
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\carl\Desktop\log.txt", result[i].Id + "\t" + result[i].Title + "\t" + result[i].ExplicitlyTrashed.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }

        // prints 3120 Lines
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\carl\Desktop\log.txt", "" + i + Environment.NewLine);

        //Count = 3120
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\carl\Desktop\log.txt", "" + result.Count);

        return result;

    }
```

Word failed to give me the right the linecount, so I did it over my Function.
But I can find the FileId 2-3 times in the File.

Comment: `FileList files = await request.ExecuteAsync();` and then `result.AddRange(files.Items);` doesn't look right at all. If that's executing asynchronously, then `files.Items` won't necessarily be ready/the request completed prior to trying to add the range of results.

Comment: I thought with the TAP-Model this should be no problem. What do I have to change so this works (with TAP)?

Comment: In my last comment somehow I missed the `await` specified, so potentially makes my last input somewhat irrelevant. I would still call the non-async method version if exposed.

Comment: You'll need to expand a bit on the 3000 and 6000. Why 3000? Are you sure you've filtered out trashed files? Does the 6000 include shared files? When you say 2-3 times, you mean the file title is duplicated or have you confirmed that the ID is duplicated (ie true duplication v. multiple files with the same title). Bottom line is you'll need to find a file that shouldn't be there and investigate that file in detail.

Comment: My query should filter the trashed files. And yes the ID is duplicated (i didnt search for filenames). For other details please see Update1.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write on the comments yet, so according to the [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)
 from google

"Note: This method returns all files by default. This includes files with trashed=true in the results. Use the trashed=false query parameter to filter these from the results."

So can you check what url of the rest api is actually being called? It seems you need to put some filters on the List method.

Comment: I've now put a filter for "trashed = false" into my function. As you can see I took the function from the DOC ([method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#examples)). But I think the problem is with the nextPageToken.

Comment: I don't know how to check that, but it should work the way it is because the code is from Google itself.

Comment: @carlilord There is a form at the end of the google api reference link, have you tried that to check if you also get the repeated files there?

Comment: tried it but I only got 300 Files (with no repeated ones).